# Accuracy of Division of Large Numbers

Tags: arithmetic

The general rule when dividing two numbers is that the answer should be given to the minimum number of significant figures of the numerator and denominator.  So, $\frac{0.43}{2.546}= 0.168892…$ but can only be reliably accurate to 2 s.f. (from the numerator) so ${0.17}$.

My question is: what is the rule when dividing large numbers when they have been pre-rounded to a particular number of significant figures?

Google says that there are $1.252\times10^9\text{ people}$ in India with an area of $3.288\times10^6 \text{ km}^2$.  Directly calculating the population density without taking into account any rounding of those figures gives $381\text{ people per km}^2$ to the nearest whole number.

Let’s imagine that these figures were only provided to 2 s.f. so there are approximately $1.3\times10^9\text{ people}$ in India and the area of India is approximately $3.3\times10^6 \text{ km}^2$.  So, the population density is $\frac{1.3\times10^9}{3.3\times10^6}\text{ people per km}^2$.  This equates to $393.\overline{93}$.  Rounding to the nearest “whole person per square km” would give $394$.

However, as the inputs have only been given to 2 s.f., should I round the answer to 2 s.f., i.e the answer would be $390$ to 2 s.f.?

But the range of numbers that the population could be would be from $1,250,000,000$ to $1,349,999,999$ and the area would be $3,250,000$ to $3,349,999$.  Using those extremes would give us a minimum population density of $\frac{1,250,000,000}{3,349,999} = 373.13$ and a maximum of $\frac{1,349,999,999}{3,250,000} = 415.38$.

So, my answer of $390$ isn’t correct either.

What would be the correct answer to “what is the population density of India if there are $1.3\times10^9\text{ people}$ in India and the area of India is approximately $3.3\times10^6 \text{ km}^2$?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can say you presented a counterexample to "general rule". So better  take a result using 1 less significant figures.

Comment: Population (esp of India) is constantly changing, and only a rough estimate can ever be given. I would say you error margins are within a reasonable bound, given current (constantly changing) statistics - bearing in mind thast birth and death rates are estimatesd, and many are not recorded. (Hence not really a maths question).

Comment: I've never heard of that general rule. But I would say that it's better to do calculations on the most accurate numbers you have available and then round the results for presentation. Also, what do you need this for? If you're just running what-ifs in your head maybe 390 is just fine. If you're making policy decisions on these numbers, maybe it behooves you to have the most accurate numbers that you can practically get.